# useEffect local state behavior after it get updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this reactjs doc example about custom hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useFriendStatus(friendID) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  return isOnline;
}
```

we suppose tnhat is called by this `Foo` component

```
function Foo(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({...});
  ...
  useFriendStatus(friendID)
  ...
}
```

When `handleStatusChange` is invoked and the `useEffect` local state `isOnline` change, what will happend ?

will the `Foo` component get rendered **more or less immediately** (i know *setState*() is asynch) or it will wait until its own `state` or `props` gets updated ?

in my knowledge a custom hook will be invoked only when the component which call it is rendered or am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When handleStatusChange is invoked and the useEffect local state isOnline change, what will happend ?
>
> will the Foo component get rendered more or less immediately (i know setState() is asynch) or it will wait until its own state or props gets updated ?

Setting state is what *causes* react components to rerender. As soon as you call setIsOnline, the component's state has been updated, and it rerenders more or less immediately.

> in my knowledge a custom hook will be invoked only when the component which call it is rendered or am i wrong ?

Custom hooks are a convenience: they let you reuse code, or simply make your code more readable. But they don't change what react knows. React just knows that you called `useState`, `useEffect`, and later `setIsOnline`. It doesn't know whether that code is written inline or extracted to a helper method.

If React sees a call to useState while rendering, it will set up a state variable and a setter function. If you call that setter function, it will rerender the component.

Comment: I got it but I update my first question if you want change something